# An invalid argument was supplied in socket programming

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, udpclient

I want to create a UDP client and server in C# and when I run those, after first send and receive message, this error implement. My code is:

```
byte[] barray = new byte[1024];
EndPoint ipre = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 4040);
socketClint.Bind((IPEndPoint)ipre);
int rc = socketClint.ReceiveFrom(barray, ref ipre);

if (rc > 0)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add("Server: "+ BitConverter.ToInt32(barray,0));
}
```

This error is about `socketClint.Bind((IPEndPoint)ipre);` line.

the Error is:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException was unhandled
HResult=-2147467259
Message=An invalid argument was supplied
Source=System
ErrorCode=10022
NativeErrorCode=10022
StackTrace:
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at client1.Form1.getmsg() in c:\Users\Inspiron 1545\Desktop\UDP\client1\client1\Form1.cs:line 38
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

InnerException:

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You can only bind one socket to an address.

Comment: is it possible to explain that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Winsock error 10022 is [`WSAEINVAL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668.aspx#WSAEINVAL):

> WSAEINVAL
>   10022
>
> Invalid argument.
>   Some invalid argument was supplied (for example, specifying an invalid level to the `setsockopt` function). **In some instances, it also refers to the current state of the socket** — for instance, calling `accept` on a socket that is not listening.

In the context of the Winsock [`bind()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737550.aspx) function (which `Socket.Bind()` uses internally), it means this:

> WSAEINVAL
>
> An invalid argument was supplied.
>
> **This error is returned if the socket `s` is already bound to an address.**

Once a socket has been bound to a local address, you can't re-bind it to a new local address.  You are supposed to bind it only one time.

So, in your case, call `Bind()` after creating `socketClint` only. Do not call it before every call to `socketClint.ReceiveFrom()`.

Comment: how we can have multi socket?

Comment: @Alireza.Doustmohammadi please clarify your question